# How to set observable properties on a controller

Tags: ember.js

In order to have values in a controller, usually I do:

```
this.name = value;
```

But this can not be done if the property must be observed: use of `.set` is required. But doing `this.set('name', value);` on a controller will set the property on the corresponding model, which is not what I want; it clutters the model with data which will anyway not be sent to the server.

Is it possible to set an observable property on a controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can add properties to a controller. In the example below the property "valueToObserve" is added:

```
    App.TestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        valueToObserve: 1,

        observerFunction: function() {
            console.log('valueToObserve has changed');
        }.observes('valueToObserve'),

        actions: {
          someAction: function() {
            this.set('valueToObserve', 2);
          }
        }
    });
```

Whenever the `valueToObserve` changes the function `observerFunction` is fired. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have not tested it, but if that works as my code does, the property will be added to the model, if that exists - which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: In my Ember app the properties defined directly on the controller are not sent to the server with `model.save()`. Perhaps I'm missing somewhere to look ...

Comment: They are not *sent* to the server, by they are still set in the model, which for me does not make sense. If those properties are not meant  to be sent to the server, they should just be set in the controller. But it seems that `.set()` does some kind of magic, and sets the property in the underlying model.

Comment: Are you sure they are set in the model? If I observe the app with the ember inspector the properties are only set in the controller and not in the model.

Comment: Interesting. What ember / ember-data are you using?

Comment: ember: 1.3.1
ember-data: 1.0.0-beta.6

Comment: I am stuck with ember-data 0.0.14 because the newest version does not support embedded objects :(